# How to break a void method in java

Tags: java, try-catch

I need to exist from a method in a point how can I do that in Java?

```
void print(){
    try{
        coding...
    //I need to exist from the print method here.
    }catch(){}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `return` statement without a return value :

```
void print(){
    try{
        coding...
        return;
    }catch(){}
}
```